# If a Dutch/Indian couple register their baby's birth with India, does it cease to be Dutch due to "voluntarily adopting" another citizenship?

Tags: india, citizenship, netherlands, dual-citizenship

Section 4 of [*The Citizenship Act, 1955* (as amended by subsequent law)](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/bitstream/123456789/1522/1/a1955-57.pdf) states that a child born outside India to an Indian parent has Indian "citizenship by descent" (which can coexist with citizenships of other countries until the child reaches "full age"), but then caveats this with a further condition that:

> a person shall not be a citizen of India by virtue of this section, unless his birth is registered at an Indian consulate...
> (i) within one year of its occurrence ...; or
> (ii) with the permission of the Central Government

Dutch law, meanwhile, permits Dutch citizens to simultaneously hold other nationalities but [not to voluntarily adopt them](https://ind.nl/en/dutch-citizenship/losing-dutch-nationality). Typically this would mean that if your circumstances of birth qualify you for automatic citizenship of multiple countries, including the Netherlands, and none of the other countries have restrictions on holding multiple citizenships by birth, then you are a citizen of all of them (since you acquired the non-Dutch citizenships *automatically*, not "voluntarily", and Dutch law permits this), but that if you naturalize in a foreign country (a *voluntary* act), you cease to be Dutch.

Indian citizenship by descent for a baby born outside India does not perfectly match the typical case, though, because it's not *completely* automatic; a voluntary act (registering his birth at an Indian consulate) is needed to secure the baby's Indian citizenship. As a matter of Dutch law, does this act constitute the baby *voluntarily adopting* another nationality and therefore cause him to forfeit his Dutch citizenship?

I can imagine multiple interpretations of how the registration requirement in The Citizenship Act works:

- a baby born to an Indian parent outside India *is an Indian citizen* at the moment of birth, but *loses* their Indian citizenship after one year if the birth is not registered. Or maybe...
- a baby born to an Indian parent outside India *is not an Indian citizen* at the moment of birth, and *becomes* an Indian citizen when the birth is registered. Or maybe...
- at the moment of such a baby's birth, the matter of whether the baby has Indian citizenship is indeterminate, like the life or death of Schrödinger's cat, and will be determined retroactively. If the birth is registered within a year, then as a retroactive consequence, the baby was *always* Indian, from the moment of his birth. If the birth is not registered within a year, then as a retroactive consequence, the baby was *never* Indian. Any legal questions that arise in the baby's first year of life and are in some way contingent on the baby's citizenship status are likewise *retroactively* answered by the registration or non-registration of his birth.

I have no idea which of these interpretations is correct. The second and third both appear to me to be fully consistent with the wording of the Act, and the first option (with automatic forfeiting) could probably work somehow. (It's a bit more complicated because it's then unclear how registering a birth after the 1 year deadline with Central Government consent works; you'd need to handle that differently to registration within the 1-year deadline. Still, not impossible; for all I know, maybe the courts have ruled that's how it works?)

If either the first or third interpretation is correct, then our hypothetical Dutch/Indian mixed baby should be safe from losing Dutch citizenship as a consequence of his parents registering his birth with India. If the *second* interpretation is correct, and the baby *acquires* Indian citizenship when his birth is registered, then things might be more problematic (though even then, perhaps there is no problem; perhaps the citizenship was not "voluntarily" acquired, either because the baby is a baby and had no say in the matter, or because the citizenship was granted as an automatic, non-voluntary consequence of registering the birth and voluntarily registering the birth is not considered the same thing as voluntarily acquiring the citizenship).

Is this a matter of settled law? Can Dutch/Indian couples safely register a baby's birth with an Indian consulate without losing the baby his Dutch nationality?

Answer (score 2):

### No

First, you have a very advanced child if they are capable of filling out and submitting government forms before their first birthday. I’m University educated and some government forms baffle me. The point is, if a *parent* submits the form, the child isn’t doing anything voluntarily.

Second, the child is not *acquiring* another citizenship, they are Indian (and Dutch) at birth. There is an administrative process that must be followed to prevent it being lost, but it isn’t an acquisition.

Finally, even if this was a voluntary acquisition (which it isn’t), there’s an [exemption](https://www.government.nl/binaries/government/documenten/publications/2017/10/05/minors-and-loss-of-dutch-nationality/Minors+and+loss+of+Dutch+nationality+-+2020+february+-+DEF+21402241.pdf) (2.a.) for as long as at least one parent is still Dutch.

Comment: "Second, the child is not acquiring another citizenship, they are Indian at birth. There is an administrative process that must be followed to prevent it being lost" Where do you get that? A child who is under 1 and not registered, does not satisfy either of the conditions quoted, and therefore, if you take the quoted text literally, is not an Indian citizen, even if one of the conditions might subsequently be satisfied before they turn 1.